# Ruport - undefined method `each' for "":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, reporting, ruport

I am following the first example in this tutorial: http://ruportbook.com/printable_documents.html, but I'm getting undefined method `each' for "":String all the time, I created a new file with this code:

```
class MultiTableController < Ruport::Controller    
  stage :multi_table_report    
  class PDF < Ruport::Formatter::PDF    
    renders :pdf, :for => MultiTableController    
    build :multi_table_report do
      data.each { |table| pad(10) { draw_table(table) } }
      render_pdf
    end    
  end    
end
```

Then, in an existing controller named workers_controller.rb I have the next action:

```
  def index_report
    t1 = Table(%w[a b c]) << [1,2,3] << [4,5,6]
    t2 = Table(%w[a b c]) << [7,8,9] << [10,11,12]
    pdf = MultiTableController.render_pdf(:data => [t1,t2])
  end
```

Then, I'm getting this error on my browser:

```
undefined method `each' for "1":String
```

I have tried many others examples and I get the same error.

Some help?

Comment: Can you show in what string error heppens? Doesn't looks like this code directly uses `each` on `String`

Comment: As you can see above, the error is happens at "1" string, I changed t1 = Table(%w[a b c]) << [1,2,3] << [4,5,6]
 to t1 = Table(%w[a b c]) << [[1],[2],[3]] << [[4],[5],[6]] to get some another clue, but the error now is: undefined method `each' for "[1]":String     :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`each`was a method of `String` in ruby 1.8 and it was removed in Ruby 1.9.

The reason was Unicode, or better the new encoding possibilities of ruby 1.9.

What should `String #each` do? Loop on each byte or each character? Ruby can't decide it for you, so you have to use `String#each_byte` or `String#each_char`.

In Ruby 1.8 it was no difference, a character was a byte.

---

Edit:

Just give a dirty hack a chance:

```
class String
  alias :each :each_char
end

'aaaa'.each{|x| p x }
```

But ruport seems to have other problems with Ruby 1.9 and there may be side effects.
I wouldn't recommend this hack in a bigger project, but maybe it works in small scripts.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Ruport. But there is a report on [missing ruby 1.9.2 support](https://github.com/ruport/ruport/issues/14), and on [ruby talk}(http://ruby.11.n6.nabble.com/ruport-in-ruby1-9-td3381908.html) I found _Ruport 1.x will never be Ruby 1.9 compatible unless someone else does the work, but Ruport 2 will be_ - But I found no Ruport 2.  See also my changed answer.

Comment: Hello, the hack works good, but I get other error now: "no marshal_dump is defined for class Mutex" I think that is better search another option for my reports, thk for all...!

Answer (score -1):

`String.each` in 1.8.7 works with lines, not with bytes or chars.
In 1.9 use `String.split("\n").each` instead of `String.each`. But be careful, `split` cut off delimiter, so `String.each` give string ended with "/n", when `String.split("\n").each` give string without "\n" on end.