# Error: undefined method "each" for String when running elastic-mapreduce specifying distributed cache file

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I've got the following error:

```
Error: undefined method `each' for "s3n://dico-count-words/Cache/dicoClazz.p#dicoClazzCache.p":String
```

When I run the following command line to launch a mapreduce algorithm on Amazon EMR cluster  via elastic-mapreduce, specifying a distributed cache file:

```
    ./elastic-mapreduce --create --stream \
> --input s3n://dico-count-words/Words \
> --output s3n://dico-count-words/Output \
> --mapper s3n://dico-count-words/Code/mapper.py \
> --reducer s3n://dico-count-words/Code/reducer.py \
> --log-uri s3n://dico-count-words/Logs \
> --cache s3n://dico-count-words/Cache/dicoClazz.p#dicoClazz.p
```

I followed the instructions I found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-input-distributed-cache.html).
I haven't had any issue running similar commands to create others clusters which didn't need distributed cache file. I have also managed to run this very job using the AWS console. But I would prefer to do it via the CLI.
I think it might be an issue with ruby similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788770/ruport-undefined-method-each-for-string). But I don't know aything about ruby so it's just a guess. It's also the first time that I use AWS and so elastic-mapreduce.
For your information, this is the version of ruby I have:

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

Do you have any ideas about where that error is coming from? Any suggestions to fix it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`each` is not available for the ruby `String` class.

As an example, let's look at the following:

---

```
x = "test"
x.each {|character| puts character}
>>>NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "test":String
```

---

This is what you're seeing in your code, and that's to be expected. Open `irb` in your terminal and try the following:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > x = "test"
2.0.0-p247 :002 > x.each <now hit tab twice>


2.0.0-p247 :003 > x.each_
x.each_byte       x.each_char       x.each_codepoint  x.each_line
```

You should see something close to the above. I happen to be using ruby 2.0.0-p247. Your version may differ.

`irb` supports auto complete. Here we started typing each and `irb` is making suggestions based on available options that start with `each`. As you can see, just plain `each` is not in fact an option. Instead, think of a string as an array of characters. That is `"test"` can be thought of like `["t", "e", "s", "t"]`. Given this representation, it's obvious what `x.each_char` will do - it will yield each character in the string. Thus:

```
x.each_char {|c| puts c}
```

will of course print each character of the string.

If we can see some of the code and data moving through it, it would be easier to suggest a solution for you. However, the above explanation is the reason you are throwing an error when calling `.each` on a `String`.

I hope this is helpful.